# html insert image in div tag not working in NetBeans

Tags: html, css, image, netbeans, web-applications

[image: This is when i run in NetBeans . just the frame appears .But when I run in notepad the image appears.]

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>mohit</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style> 
        body{margin: 0}
        #mohit1{
            width: 100%;
            height: 211.5px;
            background: orange;
        }
        #mohit2{

            width: 100%;
            height:211.5px;
            background: white

        }
        #mohit3{
            width: 100%;
            height: 211.5px;
            background: green;
        }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>

    <div id="mohit1"></div>
    <div id="mohit2"> <center> <img src="C:/Users/WELCOME/Desktop/flag.png" width="210" height="210" alt="chakra" /> </center> </div>
    <div id="mohit3"></div>

</body>
```

When i run this page in netbeans it just shows the frame of the image with defined width and length and not the actual image. But if i run with notepad it runs fine.

Comment: Can you make it jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you have an absolute image source, which will work fine if you just load the HTML file into the browser because it knows to look on your own file system. When using Netbeans I believe it sets up a local webserver and the browser tries to get the file from `localhost/C:/Users/WELCOME/Desktop/flag.png`

and the webserver does not know what to do and there will be an empty response. The way to fix this would be to put the image file in a relative folder for example: 
 `C:/path/to/project/img/flag.png`

and changing the src attribute to `img/flag.png`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Because, you're using an absolute image path. Use relative path to an image in your HTML page. In order to achieve this create one directory called `images` under `Web Pages` directory like below,

[image: snap 1]

And paste the image inside that folder. In your HTML file use like this

```
<body>
    <div id="mohit1"></div>
    <div id="mohit2">
        <center>
            <img src="images/ashoka_chakra.png" width="210" height="210" title="chakra" />
        </center>
    </div>
    <div id="mohit3"></div>
</body>
```

If you have any confusion with your relative path, place your pointer inside `src=""` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> you'll get auto completion like below in Netbeans

[image: snap 2]

Here is the final output

[image: snap 3]

Comment: i did the same as u said but instead of the actual image i am justgetting the name which i put under alt tag

Comment: May be your relative path to image is not correct. As I said in my answer use control space to get correct path. If you're using separate folder for `HTML` pages then the relative path might be `../images/ashoka_chakra.png` And be sure to create `images` folder under `Web Pages`.

Comment: i used control space for inserting path but still the same problem . My images folder is also under web pages

Comment: Can you post Netbeans project file structure screenshot like I posted in my answer. So, that I can easily understand your problem.